# LINQ Entity conversion of dynamic SQL with multipe Left Outer Joins to same table

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, left-join

Trying to convert PL/SQL to LINQ to Entity.  I'm still unclear as to how to apply an OUTER JOIN to the same table, against > 1 of the (virtual) tables in the original FROM clause and adding additional WHERE's.

A simplified version of the PL/SQL being converted:

```
query1 := 'SELECT person.id, sub1.descrpt, sub2.POB
           FROM person, gift
              ,(SELECT address.street
                       ,Address.addressDetail as descrpt
                FROM Address
                     Abbrevs
                WHERE address.stateID = Abbrevs.stateID
                  AND Abbrevs.stateName = 'Nevada')  AS sub1
              ,(SELECT address.street
                       ,Address.addressDetail as POB
                FROM Address
                     Abbrevs
                WHERE address.stateID = Abbrevs.stateID
                  AND Abbrevs.stateName = 'California') AS sub2
          WHERE person.address    = sub1.street(+)
            AND person.POB        = sub2.street(+) '

IF (somethingTrue) THEN
   query1 := query1 || ' AND blahBlah ' ;
END IF;
```

From other posts, I've tried :

```
var sub1ALL = (from addr in Address
              join abbrev in Abbrevs on addr.stateID = abbrev.stateID
              where abbrev.stateName = 'Nevada'
              select new 
              {
                  addr.street,
                  pob = addr.addressDetail
              });

var sub2ALL = (from addr in Address
              join abbrev in Abbrevs on addr.stateID = abbrev.stateID
              where abbrev.stateName = 'California'
              select new 
              {
                  addr.street,
                  description = addr.addressDetail
              });

var query1 = (from pers in Person
              from subq1 in sub1ALL
                  .Where( p=> p.street == subq1.street).DefaultIfEmpty()
     // ??? 2nd outer join to Person with sub2???? :
              from pers in Person       // ???
              from subq2 in sub1ALL     // ??
                  .Where( p=> p.POB == subq2.address).DefaultIfEmpty()  // ??
              from gift in gifts
              ...
```

It seems that this is shorthand for the above so far. 
I've been reading up on how to then append the dynamically determined WHERE clause by then stating:

```
if <pred> 
    query1 = query1.Where ( x=> x.POB_or_whatever );
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You might not have to use joins if the database has it's foreign keys set up properly. Do you know if it does?

Comment: Some but not all, and not certain which do / don't at this point.  I've also added my latest attempt at 'simplifying' via .Where() usage.